# How to get the View Object from ViewsBlock?

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I'm loading a variable list of blocks. In some cases these blocks are a views_block type. When I load a views_block, the viewsblockbase provides the protected View object, but does not provide a method to retrieve it.

How would I go about retrieving the full view object from a views_block?

I considered a ViewsBlock::Create() approach however this would be redundant which Im trying to avoid. Likewise, I have the view_id and display_id but would rather not Views::GetView() when the object is already sitting right there in the loaded block.

snippet

```
<?php

public function buildDashboard() {
  // $block_instance = new DashboardBlockManager;
  $block_instance = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  $blocks = $this->getBlocks();
  foreach ($blocks as $region => $region_blocks) {
    foreach ($region_blocks as $index => $block_id) {

      //$block_id example views_block:dashboard_tasks_by_assignee-block_1

      $load_block = $block_instance->createInstance($block_id);

      $title = $load_block->label();
      $build_block = $load_block->build();
      $build_block['#block_title'] = $title;

      //check the plugin type
      $definition = $load_block->getPluginDefinition();

      if ($definition['id'] == 'views_block') {
        //cant do this
          $view = $load_block->view;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to get the the view Object directly it's protected property and there is no method to get it:
From [ViewsBlockBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21ViewsBlockBase.php/class/ViewsBlockBase/8.2.x)

> /**
>      * The View executable object.
>      *
>      * @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable
>      */
>     protected $view;

But there is a way first get the view id from the `DerivativeId` and then load the view here is a code snippet below:

```
  use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

  $blockManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  $contextRepository = \Drupal::service('context.repository');
  // Get blocks definition.
  $definitions = $blockManager->getDefinitionsForContexts($contextRepository->getAvailableContexts());
  $views_blocks = [];
  foreach ($definitions as $id => $definition) {
    $id_type = explode(':', $id);
    if ($id_type[0] == 'views_block') {
      /** @var \Drupal\views\Plugin\Block\ViewsBlock $viewsBlock */
      $viewsBlock = $blockManager->createInstance($id);
      $derivativeId = $viewsBlock->getDerivativeId();
      $derivativeId_exploded = explode('-', $derivativeId);
      $view_id = $derivativeId_exploded[0];
      $view = Views::getView($view_id);
      $views_blocks[] = $view;
    }
  }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thats was what I was trying to avoid, but I suppose if that's what needs to be done so be it. thanks